# spring integration max-fetch-size info

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

We want to use spring boot 1.5.8 with spring integration 5.x as it has one attribute(max-fetch-size) for sftp inbound channel adapter which allows you to control no. of files being downloaded locally from sftp server. Is it possible to use spring integration 5.x with spring boot 1.5.8?

I cannot use spring boot 2.0 M7 release in production as it is not allowed in our company and as spring boot 2.x is not release yet and we have to go to production in March , we need workaround.

If this is not possible, how can i implement max-fetch-limit with spring integration 4.x version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not currently any plans to back-port that feature to 4.3.x.

As an alternative, you could use an [SFTP Outbound Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) to GET a single file instead of using the inbound channel adapter.

Spring Boot 2.0 is currently scheduled to be released in February so, perhaps, that fits your timeline.